# Given the cartesian coordinates of four points, how to calculate the interection of two lines they form?

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

Given four complex numbers $A, B, C, D$ interpreted as points on the plane, how can I calculate the number that represents the intersection of the lines formed by $A, B$ and $C, D$?

Comment: Assuming $\arg(B-A)\neq\arg(D-C)$ of course...

Comment: @J.M. Of course. This possibility is ruled out.

Comment: *Mathematica* says: $$\frac{(A-B)\Re(D\Im C-C\Im D)+(C-D)\Re(A\Im B-B\Im A)}{\Re((A-B)\Im(C-D)-(C-D)\Im(A-B))}$$

Comment: @J.M. Oh yeah. That looks good. THank you! BTW, is there a solution that use the $r,\vartheta$ representation instead?

Comment: @J.M. Could you please provide the Mathematica input that you used to generate your equation:
(A−B)R(DJC−CJD)+(C−D)R(AJB−BJA)R((A−B)J(C−D)−(C−D)J(A−B)) I imagine you used Solve[..], but I'm wondering how you told Mathematica to split up the complex numbers like that Thanks

Comment: @tlatev: I don't have *Mathematica* with me at the moment, but if memory serves, I used Cramer's rule and some massaging with `ComplexExpand[]` and `Simplify[]` in all the right places...

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ is the intersection, then we're seeking $r,s\in\mathbb{R}$ with
$$
P = A + r(B-A) = C + s(D-C).
$$
(If you are familiar with linear fractional transformations, note that the map
$P\rightarrow\frac{P-A}{B-A}=r$ takes $A$ to $0$, $B$ to $1$ and fixes $\infty$,
and similarly for $P\rightarrow s$.)

This can be rewritten using constant "vectors" $X=A-B$, $Y=D-C$ & $Z=A-C$ as
$$
\begin{matrix}
r(A-B) &+& s(D-C) &=& A-C \\
rX &+& sY &=& Z
\end{matrix}
$$
which becomes two equations in two unknowns over $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
r\;\Re{X} &+& s\;\Re{Y} &=& \Re{Z} \\
r\;\Im{X} &+& s\;\Im{Y} &=& \Im{Z}
\end{matrix}
$$
where $\Re{(x+yi)}=x$ and $\Im{(x+yi)}=y$ are the real and imaginary
components of any complex number in the identification
$\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$. This has solution
$$
r = \frac{
  \left|
    \begin{matrix}
      \Re{Z} & \Re{Y} \\
      \Im{Z} & \Im{Y}
    \end{matrix}
  \right|
}{
  \left|
    \begin{matrix}
      \Re{X} & \Re{Y} \\
      \Im{X} & \Im{Y}
    \end{matrix}
  \right|
}
= \frac{\Im{(Z\overline{Y})}}{\Im{(X\overline{Y})}}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
P=A-rX,
$$
since for any $X,Y\in\mathbb{C}$ (as is easy to verify),
the determinants above can be expressed in several equivalent ways:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
  \left|
    \begin{matrix}
      \Re{X} & \Re{Y} \\
      \Im{X} & \Im{Y}
    \end{matrix}
  \right|
  &=&
  \Re{X}\Im{Y}-\Re{Y}\Im{X} & \\
  &=&
  \Re(X\Im{Y}-Y\Im{X}) & \qquad\text{(as in the Mathematica answer)} \\
  &=&
  -\Im{(X\overline{Y})} & \qquad\text{(as used above)}.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = (x_1,y_1), \dots , D = (x_4, y_4)$ be your four complex numbers. The pair of straight lines joinning the first and the second and the third and the fourth can be represented by the parametric equations

$$
(x,y) = s(x_1, y_1) + (1-s) (x_2, y_2) \ , \qquad s \in \mathbb{R} \qquad\qquad [1]
$$

and

$$
(x,y) = t(x_3, y_3) + (1-t) (x_4, y_4) \ , \qquad t \in \mathbb{R} \qquad\qquad [2]
$$

So we have to solve

$$
s(x_1, y_1) + (1-s) (x_2, y_2) = t(x_3, y_3) + (1-t) (x_4, y_4) \ .
$$

That is,

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(x_1 -x_2)s + (x_4 - x_3)t & = & x_4 - x_2 \\
(y_1 -y_2)s + (y_4 - y_3)t & = & y_4 - y_2 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

So, you just find the solutions, $s$ or $t$, of this system of linear equations, and then replace in [1] or [2].